# How to get the domain name from the request in a Java servlet?

Tags: java, http, servlets

If a single servlet serves data from two domains `example1.com` and `example2.com`, how do you retrieve the domain information from the request in a Java servlet?

The purpose is to perform different actions depending on the domain.

Comment: Hi Bacon, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 14):

Very easy, [javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getServerName()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29). It also provides [further methods](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) to retrieve request information, `getScheme()`, `getServerPort()`...

Edit: If you have a web server guarding your application server, it must be configured to support this, otherwise `getServerName()` returns the name of your application server which may not be what you want...

Comment: This is wrong, getServerName: Returns the host name of the server to which the request was sent. It is the value of the part before ":" in the Host header value, if any, or the resolved server name, or the server IP address. To get the domain from te client request, do: String domain = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString()).getHost();

Comment: OncePerRequestFilter eg: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-onceperrequestfilter
then in that request :String domain = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString()).getHost(); to get the domain of the request
and match it with  valid domain names and reject or accept request based on that