# How to get domain name for request coming through web server?

Tags: apache, servlets

I have 2 domains. `http://sender.com/someServlet/`  and `http://receiver.com/someReceiver`.

`someServlet` will POST some data to `someReceiver`. Flow is like below,

```
sender.com  -> Apache web server of receiver.com  -> Application server of receiver.com
```

I want to get the domain who is posting the data to receiver.com's `someReceiver` servlet.

Since, there is a Apache web server through which the request has to go through,
when I execute below code in `someReceiver` servlet, I am getting the domain of 
receiver.com instead of sender.com.

```
request.getServerName();
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300670/how-to-get-the-domain-name-from-the-request-in-a-java-servlet) post tells to do configurations to support `getServerName();` to return the actual 
sender's domain. Am not sure what configurations has to be done.

How can I get the actual domain who is posting the data?